# How to create function that returns True if string has unique characters and False otherwise

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example: `"xwzfyfjvmehjnscfdvyosifv"` should return `False`, since it has several `"f"` (among other repeted chars)

while `"fnyqov"` should return True.

My problem is that most of the time my code works, but `"xwzfyfjvmehjnscfdvyosifv"` keeps returnig `True`.

Higher and lower case should be threated as equal, so `"woOman"` should return `False`.

Here is my code:

```
def is_isogram(string):
    string = string.lower()
    if string == "":
        return True
    for i in string:
        if string.count(i) >= 2:
            return False
        elif is_repeated(string) == True:
            return False
        else: 
            return True

def is_repeated(string):
    last_letter = ""
    for i in string:
        if last_letter.lower() == i.lower():
            return True
            break
        last_letter = i
    return False

print(is_isogram("xwzfyfjvmehjnscfdvyosifv"))
```

Comment: `if len(set(string)) != len(string): ` ... Use `string.lower()` for case-insensitive set build.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @zwer, I use string.lower() in the beginning of the function to deal with that problem. I didn't really understand where `if len(set(string)) != len(string):` fits and how it actually would solve my problem.

Comment: Sets can store only unique values so turning your string into a set would get rid off the duplicates - consequently, if there were any duplicates its length will differ than the length of the original string. I suggest you to do some read up on Python data structures, specifically sets in this case to understand it better. You can start with the [`official documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: Such a simple problem to solve and I spent hours there... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def is_unique(test):
    test = test.lower()
    for c in test:
        if test.count(c) != 1:
            return False
    return True

test1 = "xwzfyfjvmehjnscfdvyosifv"
test2 = "woOman"
test3 = "abcdefghijklmnop"

is_unique(test1)
>>>False
is_unique(test2)
>>>False
is_unique(test3)
>>>True
```

Or use set()

```
len(set(test1.lower()))==len(test1)
>>>False
len(set(test2.lower()))==len(test2)
>>>False
len(set(test3.lower()))==len(test3)
>>>True
```

Comment: NOTE: **Do not** use the first approach with [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) - it's incredibly inefficient (`O(n²)`) for such a simple task.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `set`:

```
def unique(s):
    return len(set(s.lower())) == len(s)
```

`set` will remove duplicates, so you can compare its length to the original.

Comment: need to change ```len(set(s))``` to ```len(set(s.lower()))``` as "woOman"  would return True

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
def func(string):
    if len(set(string.lower())) == len(string.lower()):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Why the whole `if .. else` play when you can directly return the comparison result, i.e. `return len(set(string)) != len(string)` ? Also, no need for `string.lower()` call on the direct length comparison as it won't change the length of the string.

Comment: This gives the opposite results the OP wants. `xwzfyfjvmehjnscfdvyosifv` is returning `True` and `fnyqov` is returning `False`. Should be the other way around

Comment: @zwer I wrote it this way so he may understand it better :')